# Unpacking dictionaries of lists

Tags: python-3.x

The following fails in Python 3.5:

```
for key, (a, b) in {'my_key': ('foo', 'bar')}:
  print(key, a, b)
```

with:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Why is it unable to unpack the tuple properly?

Comment: Have you looked at how Python iterates over dicts? It only iterates over the keys if you use a default for... in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `items()` method on the dictionary, it will work.

```
>>> for key, (a,b) in {'my_key': ('foo','bar')}.items():
...     print(key, a, b)
...
my_key foo bar
```

See: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)